# ICC on Linux: link to OpenMP

Tags: c++, openmp

What are the steps to link to OpenMP with Intel C++ compiler? Does Intel compiler ship with its own OpenMP library or should I link to **libgom**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It comes with its own implementation apparently. You don't need to specify additional libraries as long as you compile with the `-openmp` flag.

```
$ icc -openmp t.c
$ ldd ./a.out 
    ...
    libiomp5.so => /opt/intel/Compiler/11.1/072/lib/intel64/libiomp5.so (0x00007fd8e7ac6000)
    ...
```

Comment: Somehow -openmp alone doest do it. I am getting 'undefined reference to __kmpc_begin' linker error. Need to link to libiomp5 explicitly.

Comment: @pic11: that's actually quite strange given the icc man page. It even has a `-openmp-link` option that allows you to select static/dynamic linking for openmp. I'm pretty sure it's supposed to be handling the libraries on its own.

Comment: @pic11: are you using iccvars to setup the compiler? What version of icc are you trying to use? Are you trying to link statically or dynamically? What version of linux are you using?

Comment: You need to make sure that you both compile _and link_ with `icc -openmp`.  `icc -openmp -c t.c -o t.o; icc t.o` won't do it, you need `icc -openmp -c t.c -o t.o; icc -openmp t.o`.

Answer (score 5):

The Intel C++ Compiler provides its own OpenMP library, it does not link against libgomp. You can use the `-static-intel` flag with icc/icpc to get rid of the libiomp5.so dependency, this way your binary runs on systems that do not have installed the Intel C++ Compiler.

```
$ icpc -openmp -static-intel t.cpp
$ ./a.out
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use icc's builtin openmp implementation.  Just pass the -openmp switch on the commandline, that's it!

Answer (score 2):

Since icc version 17 `openmp` argument is deprecated:

> icc: command line remark #10411: option '-openmp' is deprecated and
>   will be removed in a future release. Please use the replacement option
>   '-qopenmp'

And icc has own openmp library.

Comment: Also, for much longer, -static-intel has not affected openmp linking.  You would still need the library path.  libiomp5 works as a replacement for libgomp (at least for the supported gcc versions), but it doesn't work the other way.